# Nodejs - Callback never called

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Suppose I write a function for some client which accept callback. What will happen if the client never call that callback

```
function a(socket){
    //some huge data
    socket.emit( 'EVENT', {
            message: "HELLO",
          }, function cb(err, res){
              // some code
          });
}
```

Suppose function is called 1000 of times, so what is the effect of this on running process.

I want to know whether this function will remain in memory or what. Any other technical details if any.

(Note - This is socket.io example but please consider it a generic example)

Comment: By "client" you mean `socket` in this case?

Comment: Well, apparently nothing will happen if the client doesn't do anything with the callback. What will happen (and whether the calls leak memory) depends (and *only* depends) on what the particular client does, so without further details about it we cannot answer anything more specific.

Comment: this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899687/what-happens-in-javascript-if-i-never-call-a-callback